# Is this a simple calculation?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Text Version

Prove that 3/4th of 1/2 of 18 is 10

[image]

Comment: Interestingly, 1/2 of 18 is also 10 ... the top half of 18, that is :)

Comment: I was certain the TH had something to do with it...three quartersth just didn't sound right...unless it's from Mike Tyson.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> 18 is *eighteen*

> 1/2 of the letters of *eighteen* are *teen*

> 3/4 of the letters of *teen* are *ten*

> *ten* is 10

Comment: That was ultra fast @xyldke!

Comment: Thanks! I got lucky that I visited the site just as your question came up. After that, it was indeed *a simple calculation*. ;)